# Corgi Engine - Character glitches with "jump" animation on top of a ladder

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, platformer, jumping

I'm new to Corgi Engine and Unity in general. I have an issue that I could find a way to resolve.

I'm using CorgiEngine's "RetroLadder" prefab and extended "Rectangle" character with custom animations from "MinimalLevel":

[image]

The problem is that when character finishes climbing the ladder, for a very short amount of time, jump animation appears. As in my case jump animation is very different from idle animation, this feels like an unpleasant glitch to me, so that's why I want to fix it. You can see it on the GIF below (at first I jump near the ladder to show how animation looks and then start climbing the ladder and on the top jump glitches) -
[image: at first I jump near the ladder to show how animation looks and then start climbing the ladder and on the top jump glitches]

I checked some other demos (e.g. RetroVania, which uses some ladders there) and they also have this "glitch" with Corgi demo character, but as the character's idle and jump animations are not very different, it doesn't seem wrong (GIF below) -

[image]

I suspect that this glitch happens because "CharacterLadder.cs" script disables gravity during ladder climbing and then enables it back which triggers fall of the character -

[image]

Do you think it's possible to workaround it somehow?

Thanks!